# Splitting string inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, dataframe

I have this column in my dataframe which has numbers in a string like `"6,22,67,82"` for example. I want to split this strings into arrays of integers and keep the arrays in the dataframe.

```
  h['htgt']=h['htgt'].split()
```

This does not work because it tries to split the whole series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` and then convert to `int`. Assumes you have an equal number of numbers in each string.

```
h = pd.DataFrame({'htgt': ['6,22,67,82', '12,45,65,14', '54,15,9,94']})

res = h['htgt'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int)

print(res)

    0   1   2   3
0   6  22  67  82
1  12  45  65  14
2  54  15   9  94
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The strings do not contain the same amount of numbers, so I am using expand is False, to keep array as entries in the column.